# How to free memory allocated on double pointer struct

Tags: c, struct, allocation

How can I free memory allocated in this struct

```
struct image_t {
    char type[3];
    int **ptr;
    int width;
    int height;
};
```

In the first function I made these allocations:

```
    struct image_t *struktura = (struct image_t *)malloc(sizeof(struct image_t));
    int **ptr = (int**)malloc(struktura->height * sizeof(int*));

    for (i = 0; i < struktura->height; i++) {
        *(ptr + i) = (int *)malloc(struktura->width * sizeof(int));
        if (*(ptr + i) == NULL) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

In the second function I must free allocated memory so I tried to free memory something like this but it does not work

```
void destroy_image(struct image_t **m) {
    if (m != NULL) {
        if (*m != NULL) {
            if ((*m)->ptr != NULL) {
                for (int i = 0; i < (*m)->height; i++) {
                    free(*((*m)->ptr + i));
                }
                free((*m)->ptr);
                free(*m);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't change declaration of the destroy function so there must be double pointer on struct.

Comment: In order to create a `**` of anything (to simulate a 2D array) it is a two-step process (1) allocate a block of `rows` number of pointers, (2) loop `rows` times allocating a block holding `cols` number of whatever type you need assigning the address to each of your pointers in turn. To free all memory, simply reverse the process, e.g. (2) loop `rows` number of times freeing each block assigned to a each pointer and then (1) make a single-call to free the pointers. (you can substitute `height` and `width` for `rows` and `cols`)

Comment: In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: Advice: If your `ptr` is a pixeldata array, I'd suggest to make it one contiguous array of data and not a two dimensional array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your destroy function to work properly, all pointers in the pointer array must be either valid or null. Memory returned by `malloc()` is uninitialized so breaking out of the loop in the allocation function leaves the rest of the pointer array uninitialized, hence should not be passed to `free()`.

Also note the you should test for allocation failure of the structure pointer and the pointer array. Furthermore the `width` and `height` members of the newly allocated structure are unintialized: you should use function arguments to initialize them.

The `destroy_image` function should probably set `*m` to `NULL` after deallocation and must `free(*m);` even if `(*m)->ptr` is a null pointer.

Here are solutions for this issue:

- allocate the array with `calloc()` (a good idea in all cases) or
- set `height` to the number of successfully allocated pointers.
- explicitly set the remaining pointers in the array to `NULL`
- free the allocated block upon allocation failure and return `NULL`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct image_t {
    char type[3];
    int **ptr;
    int width;
    int height;
};

struct image_t *allocate_image(int width, int height) {
    struct image_t *struktura = calloc(1, sizeof(*struktura));

    if (struktura == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // should initialize struktura->type too
    struktura->width = width;
    struktura->height = height
    struktura->ptr = calloc(height, sizeof(*struktura->ptr));
    if (struktura->ptr == NULL) {
        free(struktura);
        return NULL;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        struktura->ptr[i] = calloc(sizeof(*struktura->ptr[i]), width);
        if (struktura->ptr[i] == NULL) {
            // Iterate downwards on index values of allocated rows
            // (i --> 0) is parsed as (i-- > 0)
            // this test works on signed and unsigned index types, unlike (--i >= 0)
            while (i --> 0) {
                free(struktura->ptr[i]);
            }
            free(struktura->ptr);
            free(struktura);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return struktura;
}

void destroy_image(struct image_t **m) {
    if (m != NULL) {
        struct image_t *p = *m;
        
        if (p != NULL) {
            if (p->ptr != NULL) {
                for (int i = 0; i < p->height; i++) {
                    free(p->ptr[i]);
                }
                free(p->ptr);
            }
            free(p);
            *m = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really agree with these overly pedantic clean-ups upon malloc failure. If you are out of heap memory your program is likely toast and the only sensible thing to do is to stop it as gracefully as possible. In which case manual heap clean-up isn't important.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: `*m` is freed before `*m = NULL;`. The very purpose of `*m = NULL;` is to clear the dangling pointer in the caller's space. Not a perfect solution as this pointer could have been duplicated elsewhere, but a reasonable one.

Comment: @Lundin: if the structure cannot be  fully allocated, clean up and return `NULL`. If some cases, using a wrapper that aborts upon failure is fine, but in other cases it is a life threatening approach.

Comment: @chqrlie - yep, it was the use of `p` and the comparison with the original that prompted the question. Thanks.

Comment: @TruthSeeker: thanks for the edit, but your test fix was incorrect and I happen to like the elegant [*downto* operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c-c).

Comment: But it's pointless to clean-up if you were about to exit anyway. The only reason for calling free() upon exit is to catch run-time bugs related to the heap and pointers. But you only need to do that when the program terminates without errors.

Comment: @Lundin: I agree that cleaning up is vain if the program exits abruptly on error. In my example, the allocation function returns `NULL` on failure. The caller may exit or try a smaller matrix size or free some memory or ask to user... The allocation function should just try to allocate and fail gracefully. What would you say if `fopen()` leaked memory when opening the file fails?

Comment: fopen is another story. If you are running out of heap memory then you should usually just exit. If the malloc failure comes from a user asking for unreasonable amounts, then that should have been caught by sanitizing user input before calling the function. I guess it is somewhat application-specific.

Comment: @Lundin: *I guess it is somewhat application-specific.* yes indeed we agree on this. The caller knows better.

Answer (score 2):

To start with...

1. Don't cast the value returned by `malloc`
2. Don't use `*(ptr + i)` Use the equivalent but much more readable version, i.e. `ptr[i]`

Doing that changes your allocation to:

```
struct image_t *struktura = malloc(sizeof(struct image_t));
int **ptr = malloc(struktura->height * sizeof(int*));

for (i = 0; i < struktura->height; i++) {
    ptr[i] = malloc(struktura->width * sizeof(int));
    if (ptr[i] == NULL) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Here is the first problem... you never assign `ptr` to anything. In the end of the code block you need to add:

```
struktura->ptr = ptr;
```

Another problem is that both `struktura->height` and `struktura->width` are uninitialized when used. They must be assigned a value before use.

For freeing the allocated memory: Your current code is too complex. A statement like `free(*((*m)->ptr + i));` contains 3 pointer dereferences!!. That's hard to read. I'll recommend that you use a few local variables to simplify the code.

```
void destroy_image(struct image_t **m) {
    if (m == NULL) return;
    if (*m == NULL) return;
    struct image_t *t = *m;
    int **ptr = t->ptr;
    if (ptr != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < t->height; i++) 
        {
            free(ptr[i]);
        }
        free(ptr);
    }
    free(t);
    *m = NULL;  // The only reason to pass a double pointer to this
                // function is to be able to change *m. I guess
                // the prototype authoe wants the function to set
                // *m to NULL
}
```

By using these local variables the code is much easier to read than stuff like `free(*((*m)->ptr + i));`

And for the `break` in the allocation code...

It's kind of strange (a bug?) that you you don't check for NULL after the first two `malloc` and then do it inside the loop. Further it's kind of strange to use `break` as it will leave the rest of the pointers uninitialized.

Anyway - If you really want that `break` in the allocation code, you also need to take that into account when freeing memory. Something like:

```
void destroy_image(struct image_t **m) {
    if (m == NULL) return;
    if (*m == NULL) return;
    struct image_t *t = *m;
    int **ptr = t->ptr;
    if (ptr != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < t->height && ptr[i] != NULL; i++) 
        {
            free(ptr[i]);
        }
        free(ptr);
    }
    free(t);
    *m = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is needlessly complicated and inefficient. Have a look at [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

You can change the struct like this:

```
struct image_t {
    char type[3];
    int* ptr; // placeholder pointer
    int width;
    int height;
};
```

Then malloc like this:

```
struct image_t* s = malloc(sizeof *s);
s->width  = width;
s->height = height;
s->ptr    = malloc( sizeof(int[width][height]) );
```

(Remember to check the result of each malloc and stop the program if it returns NULL.)

Then use it like this:

```
int (*arr)[s->height] = (void*) s->ptr; // convert to a temporary 2D array pointer
...
arr[i][j] = whatever; // this enables 2D array access syntax
```

And free it like this:

```
free(s->ptr);
free(s);
```

Comment: Alternatively you could use old style "mangled arrays"  `s->ptr = malloc(width*height*sizeof(int));` ... `(s->ptr)[i*s->width + j]` but that's less readable.

Comment: Using a real 2D array is good advice, but 2D arrays with both dimensions variable is a C11 optional feature and cannot be specified as a structure member. Furthermore I doubt the OP can change the structure definition nor the allocation strategy: allocating a 2D array and initializing the pointer array to point to each of its rows seems more efficient but would fail if some other code reallocates individual rows.

Comment: @chqrlie No that doesn't make sense either. In that case they would need to store the individual sizes somewhere, not use two members called height and width. The structure you describe sounds like an array of structs, each struct storing data and size.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I don't understand what you mean with "technical bounds violation".

Comment: @Lundin: by *reallocating*, I meant changing the row pointers. Even if no call to `free` is performed, just swapping the first and second pointers would make the 2D array no longer freeable as its base address is no longer known.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The object that `p` points at has no effective type until you write access it. The type of the object then becomes the type used for the access. Which is actually just an `int`. So the compiler cannot make any out of bounds assumptions about `p[i][j]` for the same reason as it can't make any such assumptions from `int* p = malloc(n*sizeof *p); ... p[i] = ...`.

Comment: @Lundin -- thank you. Coffee wore off a long time ago and I fell into my own sleepy trap -- there is no array involved...